# How do I make the GHC recognize a SingI instance in this snippet?

Tags: haskell, ghc, singleton-type

had a question about [singletons](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons)

I have a promoted data type `a` where I instanced `data family Sing (a :: Foo)` appropriately.

I also have a type family `Bar (a :: Foo) (b :: Foo) :: Foo`

In the middle of a busy function, I have:

```
(\(x :: Sing n) (y :: Sing m) -> doThingsWith (sing :: Sing (Bar n m)))
```

But I'm not sure where I should put my `SingI` constraint.

For more details, my type is

```
data PNat = NZ | NS PNat

data instance Sing (n :: PNat) where
  SNZ :: Sing 'NZ
  SNS :: Sing (m :: PNat) -> Sing ('NS m)
```

and my type family is

```
type family NPlus (n :: PNat) (m :: PNat) :: PNat where
  NPlus NZ y = y
  NPlus (NS x) y = NS (NPlus x y)
```

Now, I'm actually able to manually write out explicit singleton shuffling:

```
nPlus :: forall n m nm. (NPlus n m ~ nm) => Sing n -> Sing m -> Sing nm
nPlus SNZ y = y
nPlus (SNS x) y = SNS (nPlus x y)
```

And this compiles fine...I can do

```
\x y -> nPlus x y
```

but I feel like I should be able to just use `singI` here and let the type family do both of the work.  Besides, I have a lot of functions like this, too, and would prefer to not have to do it for each one.

I do have ScopedTypeVariables turned on.

thank you all

---

Edit: Ah, I just realized that `SingI` instances aren't automatically derived; I whipped one up:

```
instance SingI NZ where
  sing = SNZ

instance SingI n => SingI (NS n) where
  sing = SNS sing
```

Unfortunately, GHC is still telling me that there is no instance of `SingI` when I use `sing` in the lambda above :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like I should be able to just use singI here and let the type
>   family do both of the work.

This can't be done. The reason why we have the many TH facilities in `singletons` is that data and function definitions must be duplicated in the current state of affairs.

The idiomatic usage would be defining everything on the term level once, and deriving the rest with TH.

```
-- LANGUAGE KitchenSink
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

$(singletons [d|
  data PNat = NZ | NS PNat deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

  nPlus :: PNat -> PNat -> PNat
  nPlus NZ y = y
  nPlus (NS x) y = NS (nPlus x y)  |])
```

This creates the `Sing` definition,the type family for `nPlus`, `SingI` instances, `SingKind` instances, the kind-restricted `SPNat` type synonym for `Sing`, defunctionalization symbols for type families and constructors, and also type-level analogues for `Eq` and `Ord`, and also [decidable equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1.2.1/docs/Data-Singletons-Decide.html). You can hit `:bro` on the module and `:i PNat` to find out exactly what got generated.

Now `nPlus` and the type family `NPlus` work as intended.

To provide a bit of explanation regarding `SingI`: `SingI a => t` is equivalent to `Sing a -> t`. They even compile to the exact same Core code. The only difference between them is that `Sing`-s are passed explicitly and `SingI`-s implicitly. `sing` provides conversion from `SingI` to `Sing`, and [`singInstance`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1.2.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#g:2) converts backwards.

In the light of this, something like

```
(SingI (NPlus n m)) => Sing n -> Sing m -> Sing (NPlus n m)
```

is pretty awkward, since it's equivalent to

```
Sing (NPlus n m) -> Sing n -> Sing m -> Sing (NPlus n m)
```

which can be implemented as a constant function that doesn't do any addition.

So when should we use `SingI` or `Sing`? The most convenient way is to perform computation on `Sing`-s, since we can pattern match on them, and use `SingI` only when we just need to plug in or pass along a value somewhere, but don't need to pattern match or recurse.

Comment: ah, thanks :) it does look like TH is the best way at the moment to really use the full power of singletons in a nice way, without lots of code duplication....